# Price rounding problems in Woocommerce and invoice system

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created an API between an accounting system and Woocommerce. Orders from Woocommerce are automatically created in the accounting system.

Everything is going well, but in some cases things go wrong with the rounding of the subtotals.

Below the order overview from Woocommerce:
[image: Order overview in WC-admin]

Below the generated invoice from the accounting system:
[image: Generated invoice]

I am aware of the Woocommerce feature: 'Round taxes by subtotals, instead of by line'. This does not solve the problem.

Previously I thought the problem was with the coupon code, but it happens at other times as well.

I have the impression that Woocommerce uses a different rounding method than my accounting system. However, I cannot find out how to solve this.

I already round the prices from Woocommerce in my code:

```
$line_items[] = array(
            
                'description' => $item_data['name'],
                'units' => $order->get_item_meta($item_id, '_qty', true),
                'amount_per_unit'=>array(
                    'value' => round($price,2),
                    'currency'=> 'EUR'
                ),
                'vat' => $tax,
                'ledger_account_id' => get_option( 'jortt_grootboek_categorie_product')
```

Comment: Most often such errors turn up when one path is calculating the percentage once on the subtotal and the other path is calculating it on each item.